# ASP.NET HTML Restar Fechas

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en este tema y me gaste unas buenas horas hacer funcionar este código pero.

Tengo el siguiente código para restar dos fechas que se alimentan de dos inputs con id num1 y num2 pero:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label  class="control-label">Total Dias</label>
        <label  class="form-control" id="sumando" typeof="readonly"/>
        <span class="text-danger" re></span>
    </div>
    <p id="sumando">  </p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var day1, day2, difference, days;
    
            day1 = new Date(document.getElementById("num1").value);
            day2 = new Date(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    
            if (isNaN(day1) || isNaN(day2)) {
                text = "Es necesarios introducir dos números válidos";
            } else {
                //si no ponemos parseFloat concatenaría x con y
                var difference = Math.abs(day1 - day2);
                days = difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
            }
            console.log(days)
            document.getElementById("sumando").innerHTML = days;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Funciona a la maravilla pero cuando en day1 y day2 le pongo por ejemplo 25-08-2021 y en day2 23-08-2021 me dice 2 días pero realmente quiero que diga -2 días y hacer que si es negativo el campo no permita continuar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos errores en tu código:

- El objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) nunca devuelve `NaN`, en todo caso, en las pruebas que estuve haciendo aparecía `null` en consola, pero fallaba la comparación `dia1 === null`
- Es mejor analizar el valor de los campos antes de comenzar a hacer operaciones
- Quieres obtener diferencia negativa, pero...

  - Deberías hacer la resta con fecha2 - fecha1
  - Evitar el uso de `Math.abs()`, porque devuelve un valor absoluto, es decir, eliminando el signo

Corrigiendo esos detalles ya funciona como esperas:

```js
function myFunction() {
    let day1, day2, days;

    // Comparar si algún valor está vacío
    if(num1.value == '' || num2.value == '') {
        days = "Es necesario introducir dos fechas válidas";
    } else {
        day1 = new Date(num1.value);
        day2 = new Date(num2.value);
        // Diferencia en horas, sin Math.abs() porque elimina el signo
        let difference = day2 - day1;
        days = difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    }
    console.log(days);
    document.getElementById("sumando").innerHTML = days;
}
calcular.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

```html
<div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="control-label">Total Dias</label>
                        <label  class="form-control" typeof="readonly"/>
                        <span class="text-danger" re></span>
                        <input type="date" id="num1">
                        <input type="date" id="num2">
                        <button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
                    </div>
                    <p id="sumando"></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Funciono, como comentaba llevaba unas horitas tratando de hacerla funcionar y tome como ejemplo la suma en javascript por eso el NaN Gracias ya quedo